# Unable to push image to Docker Hub registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am brand new to Docker and I am trying to follow the **Getting Started** tutorial from Docker. I am using Docker 17.05-ce under Ubuntu 17.04. The problem appears to be network related. When I try to push I get the following results:

```
jonathan@poseidon:~/DockerTest$ sudo docker push jgossage/get-started:part1
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/jgossage/get-started]
1770f1c9a8cf: Pushed 
61fd1d8cd138: Pushed 
e0f735a5e86f: Layer already exists 
1de570a07fb5: Pushed 
b3640b6d4ac2: Layer already exists 
08d4c9ccebfd: Pushed 
007ab444b234: Retrying in 1 second 
dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: dial udp 127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
jonathan@poseidon:~/DockerTest$ sudo docker logs 58e8df0a7426
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2017 15:12:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

172.17.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2017 15:13:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

The push runs for some time with several retries before timing out.

This is on a home network with one computer connected to the router via WiFi and then normal TCP to my ISP and the Internet. What steps can I take to make Docker run reliably?

Comment: I'm confused. What is container `58e8df0a7426` and what does it have to do with pushing to the public registry? Also, what is 127.0.0.53:53? Are you running a local DNS server? Can you resolve `registry-1.docker.io` on this local DNS server?

Comment: So far as I know the DNS server is in the ISP. This is a vanilla 17.04 ubuntu installation and Docker is the first tool I am installing. I definitely did not create a local DNS server. Container 58e8df0a7426 is the only container on my system and was the one running when I tried to push once more.

Comment: 127.0.0.53 is a DNS stub resolver created by systemd-resolved.

Comment: Try `docker --dns 8.8.8.8 push <your-image>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by replacing the standard DNS caching and resolving DNS server with a third party implementation **unbound**. The [following web page](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/) contains complete instructions for doing this at the end of the document. As also suggested by others, it is a good idea to change to use the public Google DNS servers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a DNS issue similar to this one: https://forums.docker.com/t/fata-0025-io-timeout-on-docker-image-push/1742/9

The suggestion is to replace your current DNS (127.0.0.53) by the Google DNS (8.8.8.8).

I'm not sure if there is an open issue concerning this problem. I couldn't find one.